# Magento2 Translate cross sell, up sell and related products

Tags: magento-2.1, translate, inline-translations

we have magento 2.1.16 ce

I can't get these three title translated:
cross sell, up sell and related products

Inline translation does not work for this ...
They are not editable.

And I also have an nl_NL.csv translation file at:

```
app/design/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme_custom/i18n
```

With these lines:

"Related Products","Gerelateerde producten"
"Up-sells","Wellicht ook interessant?"
crosssell,"Wellicht ook interessant?"

but a change at this location does not work.
How can I translate these frases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look in my version of the Catalog translation file I find the following lines for the three themes

```
"Related Products","Related Products"
"We found other products you might like!","We found other products you might like!"
"More Choices:","More Choices:"
```

They are used in the `Catalog\templates\product\list\items.phtml` template which is used to generate these types of list as widgets, and they are setup properly translatable in that template. The corresponding dictionary is in the Catalog module folder.

It's probably worth trying these.

But if you are not able to use inline translation on these, and you are seeing terms like "Up-sells" on the front end, then perhaps there is a third party module or a widget in the way, and you might have to look at their settings and templates. If the title is set up in the module's admin interface for example a "custom product tabs" style module

And if it is on the back end side that you need to translate, then you need a separate theme to translate these

Comment: Thank you ...It was well hidden in the option of my theme ....

Comment: glad I could help